# How to send push notifications to Android mobile devices from application server through C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm

For sending the same message to 100 devices via c2dm, 
We need to do the following things,
1. get registration of each device that you need to send messages.
2. initiate 100 request one for each device and send it to c2dm.
Am i correct?

Do we really need to send 100 request one for each device. one request containing registration id of each device?

Is there any way that i can send all the device's registration ids in a single request with the message? so that with that request, c2dm will broadcast or push that common message to all 100 devices with that registration ids that it obtained in a single request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C2dm does not allow batch sending until now. So you still have to send them for each device.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, we need to send 100 requests to c2dm to broadcast the same message to 100 devices. If so, it is not disigned on Publish/Subscribe? and

Comment: So it is like, each requests will be proccessed one by one, it is not like braodcasting and publish/subscribe?

Comment: you should check/search on stackoverflow before you ask questions. There are quite few question already asked on this topic. If you look at the right side under "Related" topic, the third entry is the same one you have asked. for the comments, no, it is not publish/subscribe. it is baked into application and you push the message.

Comment: Is there any way to implement publish subscribe in Android ?at the same time, client should not polling server for informtion, whenever there is update, server publish and sender then receives

Comment: you can take a look at Pubsubhubbub I am not very familiar with it tho http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/

Answer (score 1):

c2dm doesnt allow batch sending. even for my application i have been sending messages with different ids, by storing the ids in a database and retrieving them in a loop. i dont think there is any better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, we need to send 100 requests to c2dm to broadcast the same message to 100 devices. If so, it is not disigned on Publish/Subscribe? and

Comment: So it is like, each requests will be proccessed one by one, it is not like braodcasting and publish/subscribe?

Comment: not broadcasting. one user at a time. I'm not very sure what you mean by publish/subscribe. if you could elaborate that please..

Comment: and if you mean the way, an RSS feed is published to every subscriber at the same time, at once, it isnt possible. like i said, you need to send to every used one at a time.

Comment: Is there any way to implement publish subscribe in Android ?at the same time, client should not polling server for informtion, whenever there is update, server publish and sender then receives

Comment: every c2dm notification allows a certain amount of message space where you can send a custom message. and the client can read this message too. so as long as your message size is small, you can send it via the c2dm notification itself. that's how I've been using my application. it completely avoids the client polling to the server for information. i hope that would solve you're problem.